# How can I sign the complete XML message using PKCS7 Standard

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, pkcs#7

I need to implement a service. On documentation, there is a part for signing procedure request message, but I didn't get it.

Here is a detail.
`Sign the complete XML message using PKCS7 Standard algorithm with attachment mode which produce the signed content. This signed content should be converted to BASE64 format as it shown below.`

I am using feign client for that implementation. How can I sign the XML message?